# Javascript inheritance misbehaviour

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have some js code here *link deleted*

If you open your js console and you'll run this code snipet

```
var r = new TempPopupForm("xxx");
r.create();
```

an error will appear

```
TypeError: this.init is not a function
```

this error is saying there is no init method implemented on this object.

But that's not true.As you can see in the code below the init method is declared.

```
TempPopupForm.prototype = new PopupForm();
TempPopupForm.prototype.constructor = TempPopupForm;
TempPopupForm.superclass = PopupForm.prototype;

function TempPopupForm(name) {
     this.init(name);
}
TempPopupForm.prototype.init = function(name) {
     TempPopupForm.superclass.init.call(this, name);
};
```

I guess something is wrong with the inheritance definition,but I can not figure out what it is.

BTW There are some third party dependencies.

EDIT

I was following this article and where the funcs are ordered like I have. The order actually works on the other classes, but not on this one.
  http://www.kevlindev.com/tutorials/javascript/inheritance/inheritance10.htm

Comment: That raw-ip address hyperlink feels suspicious...

Comment: That's my test machine, so no domain for me :-)

Comment: You don't want to use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) instead? Personally, I find it looks suspicious - making other users disinclined to follow the link or help with your problem - and you're exposing/singling-out your test machine as a target for hackers...

Comment: You're right.I moved the code to jsFiddle.

Comment: Your functions are out of order. Move the constructor and prototypes above the instantiation (new PopupForm())

Comment: The errors I get are in the fiddle are *Uncaught ReferenceError: TempPopupForm is not defined* and *Uncaught ReferenceError: $MainPage is not defined*.

Comment: $MainPage is not defined here. Why don't you have the js code in the html part of your jsfiddle in the js part of jsfiddle at the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-order your functions and instantiation. Since your constructor is using one of its own prototyped method to init, they both need to be above the block where you instantiate the object. JavaScript hoists top-level functions.

Try this -

```
function TempPopupForm(name) {
     this.init(name);
}

TempPopupForm.prototype = new PopupForm();
TempPopupForm.prototype.constructor = TempPopupForm;
TempPopupForm.superclass = PopupForm.prototype;

TempPopupForm.prototype.init = function(name) {
     TempPopupForm.superclass.init.call(this, name);
};

var r = new TempPopupForm("xxx");
r.create();
```

Comment: I reordered it like you suggested,but know it says: TempPopupForm.superclass is undefined

Comment: I made an edit... not sure if that will work or not. Why are you doing it like that anyway? Surely there is a simpler way

Comment: Now it says again : this.init is not a function. I was following this article http://www.kevlindev.com/tutorials/javascript/inheritance/inheritance10.htm

Comment: I'm not sure then... sorry I couldn't help ya